# What do square brackets do in IDA's pseudocode representation?

Tags: ida, assembly, x86-64

I've been a bit stumped recently on my decomp work. I've not dealt with C in depth nor have I dealt with IDA's pseudocode system very much at all. I understand asm, but because of how IDA merges instructions together in its pseudocode system, I'm having some trouble finding out how this translates.

In my pseudocode I have the following line:

```
// v1 is a pointer to RDI (stored as a single in pseudocode)
// v7 is a pointer to R8 (stored as a single in pseudocode)
// v10 is XMM1 (single)

v1[1818] = (float)(v10 * (float)(*v7 - v7[1])) + v7[1];
```

I'm having trouble understanding what the square brackets do. I was thinking that it was an offset (e.g. "set the data at the location of v1 in memory + 1818i64 bytes to...") but the asm doesn't match up with that addr. What's the difference between setting `v1 =` vs setting `v1[1818] =`?

Comment: In C they denote an array access. To correspond with assembly you might have to multiply the index with size of one member of the array.

Comment: Ah-ha! Yes, you were right. That was my mistake. I forgot to multiply 1818 by the size of the value (4 in this case, since it's a single). Suppose I'm just too used to the asm usage of [], yeah? I found the line `movss dword ptr [rdi+1C68h], xmm1` -- `rdi+1C68h` is indeed the right location after doing RDI+(4*1818i16).

Comment: If your problem is solved, please write a short answer, accept it and close this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found out how this works. I had the right idea, but I had made the mistake of assuming it was *n* bytes ahead, failing to factor in the size of the actual value at hand.

Since the specific type of `v1` was a single, this means I had to multiply the `1818` by `4` bytes. Looking at the corresponding ASM, `movss   dword ptr [rdi+1C68h], xmm1`, I can see that `rdi+1C68h` comes out to `v1` (rdi) + `7272i64` or `rdi+1C68h` - it checks out.